# How to specify priority in __attribute__((constructor)) for nested functions?

Tags: c, gcc, constructor, attributes, initialization

As part of some utility macro I am writing, I am defining a nested function with `__attribute__((constructor))`

However, I need those constructors to happen before other constructor defined at global space.

Unluckily though, when I specify a priority for the nested constructors they stop working altogether, and when I don't specify it they are the last to be invoked...

Here is the proof:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor(102))) void global_constructor_prio102(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__); }
__attribute__((constructor())) void global_constructor(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__); }
__attribute__((constructor(101))) void global_constructor_prio101(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__); }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%s - gcc %s\n", __func__, __VERSION__);

    __attribute__((constructor(102))) void nested_constructor_prio102(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__); }
    __attribute__((constructor())) void nested_constructor(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__); }
    __attribute__((constructor(101))) void nested_constructor_prio101(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__); }

    return 0;
}
```

And its output:

```
global_constructor_prio101
global_constructor_prio102
global_constructor
nested_constructor
main - gcc 8.1.0
```

Am I hitting a bug in GCC, or some obscure behaviour?
Is there a way to make the nested constructor run before a global one?

(repl link: https://repl.it/@agustinf_/Nested-constructors-fail-with-priority)

Comment: After more testing I found that priority 65535 kind of works but is the same as no priority.

Answer (score 1):

Nested functions cannot be validly called outside the lifetime of a particular instance of the block they're nested within. What would you expect to happen if these nested functions accessed `argv`?

This is a bug in GCC, namely that it lets you attach the `constructor` attribute to nested functions for which it is meaningless. If you want to report it, it should be reported as such. There is no expected behavior since the construct has no meaning.

Comment: Well, in my use case the nested functions are used to initialize static variables that are only accesible from the parent function, so they are not meaningless.

Comment: @gatopeich: [GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) is very sloppy about this: "If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, all hell breaks loose. If you try to call it after a containing scope level exits, and if it refers to some of the variables that are no longer in scope, you may be lucky, but it’s not wise to take the risk. If, however, the nested function does not refer to anything that has gone out of scope, you should be safe." The "should be safe" condition is almost surely obsolete...

Comment: ...in that there's nothing to guarantee the compiler does not make transformations that cause access to the stack frame of the enclosing block.

Comment: @gatopeich: There are a couple "right solutions" to your problem: either just making the static variables file-scope and using normal non-nested functions for ctors, or using `call_once`/`pthread_once` to initialize safely on first use. Being that nested functions are essentially a deprecated feature (most uses require executable stack, which is unsafe, and LLVM explicitly does not and won't support them) you should forget you ever heard of them and find a clean solution.

Comment: I had considered those options too, but for my use case I really want to be able to initialize the local static variable from the same macro instantiation that generates it. Otherwise it is not user friendly.

Comment: I am using this trick to create a register of such instances and the user should be able to list them without executing them.

Comment: IMO it is a bug in GCC in that a change in priority should not break the functionality, however fixing the bug would not solve my issue because I want this code to work on *existing* versions of GCC.

Comment: @gatopeich: The bug in GCC is simply that it syntactically allows something that is not meaningful.